# How to edit the name of many excel sheets?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a set of folders with folder names as the names of the players.
Inside the folder, I have either one excel sheet named gw or two excel sheets, gw and history.

Now, I wish to change the name of all the gw excel sheets to the name of the folder they belong to.

Here's an example: I have a folder name 'Aaron Cresswell'. Inside the folder I have two excel sheets 'gw' and 'history'. I wish to change the name of the 'gw' excel sheet to 'Aaron Cresswell'.

I can't do it manually because there are 439 such player folders.

Any help would be dearly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You are talking about Excel Files, not sheets, right? So basically, you want to rename files. What have you done so far and how is that related to all the tags you gave for this question?

Comment: Yes I mean excel files. Can VBA be helpful? I am just guessing.

Comment: You can do so with VBA, VBS, python, C#, powershell or nearly every other programming language - pick the one you are familiar with.

Comment: Can you help me with python?

Comment: If you want to use python, remove all the other tags of your question, show what you have done so far and where you are stuck. Try to understand `os.walk` and `os.rename`

Comment: I unfortunately couldn't come up with anything. I will read about the above two.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so in Python.

```
import os
base_path = r'C:\Users\Documents\<snip>'
for directory in os.listdir(base_path):
    os.rename(
             os.path.join(base_path, directory, 'gw.xlsx'), 
             os.path.join(base_path, directory, '{}.xlsx'.format(directory))
             )
```

where `base_path` is the path to the folder containing the directory of player names.